# Animation does not origin from where I want it to? Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing a countdown clock to my game. I want the numbers to be animated so they come from the middle of the screen and then fade away in the middle. But when I run the code they will come from the right bottom of the screen instead of where I specified it (160,284). What could the problem be?

```
} else if (startgameEveryInt == 3) {
    UIImageView *Object = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,284,280 ,280)];
    [Object setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
      [self.view addSubview:Object];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         Object.alpha = 0;
                         Object.frame = CGRectMake(160, 284, 50, 50);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         startgameEveryInt = 0;
                         [startgametimer invalidate];
                         startgametimer = nil;
                         [self startit];
                         for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
                             if (view.tag > 10) {
                                 [view removeFromSuperview];
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}
```

Comment: The code above does not set any initial position for the imageView, only the end-position... (Sorry, my bad).

Comment: Here: UIImageView *Object = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,284,280 ,280)];

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: It doesn't look like `setImage` scales the image for you, so unless the image is the size of the frame you're using things could go wrong (particularly if `clipToBounds` is off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your CGRect settings to for before the animation-

```
CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-160)/2, (self.view.frame.size.height-284)/2, 160, 284)
```

Then changing the size of the object as you did before to

```
CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-50)/2, (self.view.frame.size.height-50)/2, 50, 50)
```

This should work for you in the middle of the screen. The X, Y positions of the CGRect will put the top LHS points of your object to that position. This is why your object looked like it was off to the bottom right.

I hope this helps

Cheers, Jim